# How can I make a hollow cylinder of some width?

Tags: graphics3d

So I'm having trouble doing this, and I've found a way to subtract one filled cylinder from another to create it this way, but the thing is, I want to put more objects inside the hollow cylinder, but I'm not sure how to do this without subtracting the entire inside of the cylinder, including what I want to be kept inside of it. Also, I'd be open to using the Tube 3D graphic, if there's a way to make that have some thickness. If it helps, or as a starting point, here's my code so far (that doesn't work, but shows what I'm trying to create in separate pieces):

```
cyl1 = Cylinder[{{0, 5, 5}, {10, 5, 5}}, 3];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{{0, 5, 5}, {10, 5, 5}}, 4];
cyl = Graphics3D[{cub2,  cub1 }] DiscretizeRegion[
RegionDifference[cyl2, cyl1]];

oth = Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{9, 4, 4}, {9.2, 6, 6}], 
Cuboid[{9, 4.8, 6}, {9.2, 5.2, 8}], {AbsoluteThickness[5], 
 Line[{{8, 4, 2.2}, {8, 4, 7.8}}], 
 Line[{{8, 6, 2.2}, {8, 6, 7.8}}], 
 Line[{{8, 3, 2.8}, {8, 3, 7.2}}], 
 Line[{{8, 7, 2.8}, {8, 7, 7.2}}], Line[{{8, 5, 2}, {8, 5, 8}}]}}];

Show[cyl, oth]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you probably meant `cub1` and `cub2` to be `cyl1` and `cyl2` respectively; also, `cyl` should be assigned the output of `RegionDifference`, and not the `Graphics3D`, if I understand what you mean.

Here I apply those changes to your code and remove extra parts:

```
cyl1 = Cylinder[{{0, 5, 5}, {10, 5, 5}}, 3];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{{0, 5, 5}, {10, 5, 5}}, 4];
cyl = DiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[cyl2, cyl1]]

oth = Graphics3D[{
    Cuboid[{9, 4, 4}, {9.2, 6, 6}], Cuboid[{9, 4.8, 6}, {9.2, 5.2, 8}],
    AbsoluteThickness[5],
    Line[{{8, 4, 2.2}, {8, 4, 7.8}}], Line[{{8, 6, 2.2}, {8, 6, 7.8}}],
    Line[{{8, 3, 2.8}, {8, 3, 7.2}}], Line[{{8, 7, 2.8}, {8, 7, 7.2}}],
    Line[{{8, 5, 2}, {8, 5, 8}}]}
  ];

Show[cyl, oth]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That actually looks pretty nice to me!

If this is not what you intended, however, you might want to edit your question to specify your desired output.

Comment: Wow thanks so much, I didn't realize you could make the discretized region into an object and then show both. This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you.

Comment: @SmcWill You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care to have the interior, you can just use ParametricPlot3D to generate the exterior surfaces:

```
washer[innerr_, outerr_, zmin_, zmax_] := {
  Table[
     ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], z}, {z, zmin, 
       zmax}, {t, 0, 2Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
      PlotPoints -> {2, 65}, 
      BoundaryStyle -> Automatic], {r, {innerr, outerr}}], 
    Table[ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], z}, {r, 
       innerr, outerr}, {t, 0, 2Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
      PlotPoints -> {2, 65}, 
      BoundaryStyle -> Automatic], {z, {zmin, zmax}}]
    }
  Show[washer[1, 2, 0, 1], PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False]
```